# How to update the value of Cookie using perl?

Tags: perl

I am creating cookie in first file and wants to update cookie value into second file. I am using following code to read and update the value of cookie. But it is not working.

```
my $new_value = 'modify';
my %cookies = fetch CGI::Cookie;

foreach (keys %cookies) {
    ### I want to change value of NewCookie
    if($_ eq 'NewCookie')   {
        my $val_cookie = $cookies{'NewCookie'}->value;
        warn "\n value of NewCookie =>" . $val_cookie;
        $cookies{'NewCookie'}->value = $new_value; ###I don't know is it work or not
    }
}
```

I am getting this error
"Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call at"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is in this line of code:

```
$cookies{'NewCookie'}->value = $new_value;
```

`$cookies{'NewCookie'}->value()` is a method.  You are trying to assign a value to a method.  I am not that familiar with CGI::Cookie, but perhaps you need to change that line of code to look like this:

```
$cookies{'NewCookie'}->value($new_value);
```

Comment: Thanks Eric Johnson for your reply It's working. Now the issue is that how can I write this new value to browser??? I used
my $q = new CGI;
$q->header(-COOKIE => $cookies{'NewCookie'}); ### but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This one is old obv. but just for good measure - you need to bake the cookie after changing its value or any other property. In this case like this:

```
$cookies{'NewCookie'}->bake;
```